# Why the 'list()' function returns a reverse order?

Tags: php

The **[list()](http://php.net/manual/it/function.list.php)** function in PHP highlights this case in the documentation:

> **Warning**
>   list() assigns the values starting with the right-most
>   parameter. If you are using plain variables, you don't have to worry
>   about this. But if you are using arrays with indices you usually
>   expect the order of the indices in the array the same you wrote in the
>   list() from left to right; which it isn't. It's assigned in the
>   reverse order.

I don't get it completely. What does it means?

**Can you please provide an example of code that could explain the case described?**

Comment: Works fine? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/487f979f53a78148b44aa3c15b9a594d0041f540

Comment: Um, what?!? It returns left to right.... For your first example, `$third` will contain `1`, `$second` will contain `2`, `$first` will contain `3`.... that's left to right

Comment: it gives in left - right order in all cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your modification to this question.... note the example immediately above that note in the docs with coffee/brown/caffeine.... the result ***values*** are in the order that you would expect, but the ***keys*** are reversed. The entries from the `$info` array are stored in the correct entries (`$a[0]`, `$a[1]` and `$a[2]`) as left to right, but the order of the indices in `$a` is reversed because of the way the function actually executes internally.... this isn't a problem unless you're listing to an array, and expect the results ordered by their index

Answer (score 2):

```
class Ab
{
  public $a;
   function abc()
  {

     $this->a=array(10,2,30,"onkar"=>array(8,5,6));
  }
  function print()
  {

    echo "<br>printing original array";
    print_r($this->a);

    foreach($this->a as $key=>$value)
        {  
           if (strcmp("onkar",$key)!=0) 
            $temp[]=$value; 
           else
            {
                list($temp[],$temp[],$temp[])=$this->a["onkar"];
                print_r($temp);
            }
        }  
     }
}
```

Here while extracting values across key "onkar" we get 5,6,8 (original are 8,6,5)respectively as manual indicates.Hope This helps.

Comment: Executable version of your code which proves the "_we get_" is available at http://ideone.com/kAwuds

Answer (score 0):

All your examples work fine. You need to check the documentation to see how the [list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) function works.

But if you really wanted to only pass in an array with three values you could slice the first three values from the array. Like this.

```
list($first, $second, $third) = array_slice(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 0, 3);
```

Comment: PHP will ignore values from the array after the last entry in the list set has been populated anyway